# Issues with understanding functions in assembly?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

I'm given the following assembly program.

```
subl $16, %esp                              
movl $0, -4(%ebp)                               
movl $10, -8(%ebp)                              
movl $5, -12(%ebp)                              
movl $0, -16(%ebp)                              
_L1:                                
movl -16(%ebp), %eax                            
cmpl -12(%ebp), %eax                                
jge _L2                             
movl -16(%ebp), %eax                            
addl -8(%ebp), %eax                             
movl %eax, -8(%ebp)                             
movl -16(%ebp), %eax                            
addl $1, %eax                               
movl %eax, -16(%ebp)                                
jmp _L1                         
_L2:                                
movl -4(%ebp), %eax                             
addl $16, %esp
```

I'm wondering whether L1 is ever entered? I see two function definitions, one for `_L1` and one for `_L2`. But the main function never calls L1.

I see the program divided up into:

```
subl $16, %esp                              
movl $0, -4(%ebp)                               
movl $10, -8(%ebp)                              
movl $5, -12(%ebp)                              
movl $0, -16(%ebp)          




_L1:                                
movl -16(%ebp), %eax                            
cmpl -12(%ebp), %eax                                
jge _L2                             
movl -16(%ebp), %eax                            
addl -8(%ebp), %eax                             
movl %eax, -8(%ebp)                             
movl -16(%ebp), %eax                            
addl $1, %eax                               
movl %eax, -16(%ebp)                                
jmp _L1                         



_L2:                                
movl -4(%ebp), %eax                             
addl $16, %esp
```

But none of those functions are called from outside functions. So this program is just as good as:

```
subl $16, %esp                              
movl $0, -4(%ebp)                               
movl $10, -8(%ebp)                              
movl $5, -12(%ebp)                              
movl $0, -16(%ebp)
```

I come from the Python world, so this doesn't make much sense to me.

Does it actually execute L1 on the initial scan? (Without being jumped to).

Any help on this would be great - I'm just starting learning Assembly.

Comment: What instruction do you think gets executed right after `movl $0, -16(%ebp)`?

Comment: Nothing - the program ends

Comment: The CPU continues to execute instructions in the order that it encounters them. It will of course follow branches (conditional or unconditional ones, jumps, calls etc) as they are encountered.

Comment: Yeah - I'm now deducing that these are just labels for the jump statement opposed to function definitions as we'd see in other languages.

Comment: CPU has no idea of "functions" or "subroutines" and similar, it understands only single instructions, and that's what it looks for every tick, next instruction to execute, in memory at address `eip`. Also the CPU has no idea how the source was formatted, so some indentation, labels or empty lines don't count, also you can jump into the middle of multi-byte instruction opcode, effectively executing different instruction than you would expect, for example `jmp _L1+1` would execute `inc %ebp` `lock cmpl -12(%ebp), %eax` (jumping into the middle of `movl -16(%ebp), %eax` instruction opcode)